# How to use 2 projects in a Solution? Winforms and Console App C#

Tags: .net, oracle, winforms, console-application

What are the benefits? Would you do it this way?

Senerio:
Project 1 in Solution:
I am building an application (WinForms App) that allows the user to Open a XLSX, XLS, or CSV and display it on a DataGridView. Once the DataGridView loads, the user interfacee will allow the  User to select one entire column (preferrably account #s) and  then press a button to open another form with a listbox showing all of the account #s and 2 MonthCalendars allowing user to pick a Start and End Date and with a click of a button will execute my other program with all necessary parameters.

Project 2 in Solution:
The other project is a console application that will take 3 arguments (string of comma seperated values:ie: account #s "8792383,8945928952,0952092,....", Start Date in string format, End Date in string format). In this project the account number string will be split into an array or list of strings, the dates will get split up in month intervals depending on time frame ie: 01/01/2023 - 04/01/2023 will be 01/01/2023 - 01/31/2023, 02/01/2023 - 02/28/2023, 03/01/2023 - 03/31/2023, etc.
Then with all of that data the program will query the Oracle database and by selecting 50 acct #s at a time going through each month interval like 01/01/2023 - 01/31/2023 then 02/01/2023 - 02/28/2023,etc. This process will take a long time. I need better suggestions.
After all of the database querying is over and everything is in a list converted into a datatable. I want to return to the Project 1 (Winforms App) and append the new datatable to the Old table with the new data allowing the user to see data first before outputting a new CSV or XLSX spreadsheet.

Please let me know if I am over complicating it. I want to this experience to benefit my skills in anyway. I am recently a new Grad.

Also side note: I want to just be able to come in and start the program and move it to the side of my screen without the UI locking up.

I have built the Winforms and my started my Console Application. I don't want to get too far before I have put too much work into something that might now work out like I expected to. I haven't connected both projects together like using the Process.Start() method to execute my .exe from the other project because I have not built my .exe file yet in the project. The only reason I am doing it this way is because I want definite/controlled inputs into my console application. For Example when someone sends my a spreadsheet(xlsX) I want to be able to load it up, pick the column with the correct acct #s and run it against my database.

Comment: You don't need a Console Project, you can access your database using the async methods provided by the .NET layer (`[DbConnection].OpenAsync()`, `[DbCommand].ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` etc.). Using the async / await pattern, your GUI becomes responsive while performing a query. Which may introduce some new challenges: the User can now interact with the GUI, so you have to make sure you disable UI elements that could interfere with the current operation (e.g., the Button that triggers the query must be disabled in the meanwhile. But you need to do that anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need second project, merge it into one single project where function in (Project 2) described coded in class which can then run as a separate thread for long process. If you need to reuse the function in (Project 2), make it as a class library.